# Unable to download pdf in html2pdf

Tags: php, mysqli, html2pdf

I am trying to download pdf from html2pdf. Download dialog box doesn't appear and it gives error

> Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

I am trying to fetch the data from database and convert it into pdf downloadable.
Here is the code

```
<?php   
    $content = '<html><body style=" background-color:#edeff0;
    margin:0px;padding:0px;">';
    $content .= '<p>kjhj</p>'; 
    $content .= '</body></html>';
    require_once('html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php');
    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','fr');
    $html2pdf->WriteHTML($content);
    $separator = md5(time());
    $eol = PHP_EOL;
    $filename = "receipt.pdf";
    $pdfdoc = $html2pdf->Output($filename, 'D');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=receipt.pdf");
 ?>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to output the data first, and the Content-Disposition header _after_ that? That's the wrong order. Plus, I don't think you need to create these headers yourself, the method will take care of that on its own.

Comment: You can use `headers_sent` to find out where the first output was created.

Comment: I have added headers at the beginning.. Dialog box to download pdf comes.. After pdf is downloaded it shows error unable to load pdf document

Comment: Then open the downloaded file with a _text_ editor, and see what it contains.

Comment: The output document name receipt.txt is not a PDF name

Comment: Have you removed the `header` call completely, as I suggested you should? And what does the file actually contain now? That is a question you should be able to answer regardless of what file name suffix it might have ...

Comment: If i remove the header call completely it gives me error "Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file..

Comment: That doesn't make much sense, your own attempt at calling `header` should give a similar warning then. Do you have proper PHP error reporting enabled? If not, go and do that first of all. Plus, I already mentioned how you can find out _where_ the first output was created.